# express dynamic routing using multer middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

For reasons I need to be able to dynamically control the routes express uses (ie. I need to be able to enable and disable URLs/paths on the fly depending on what is set active and what isn't).
This is why express only gets 1 path added:

```js
this._express.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
            console.log(req.path);
            console.log(req.method)
            if (req.path in this._routes){
                this._routes[req.path](req, res, next);
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(404);
            }
        });
```

However, I have an upload form to send files to the server, and the normal way of using multer is as follows:

```js
let upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
express.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
 // Do stuff and have access to req.file
});
```

However, using my current method, I can't add the multer middleware to the dynamic route and I've tried to call the middleware inside of my custom route code when `/upload` is called, however, this is to no avail. Is there a way to circumvent having to hard pass my routes to express and still use middleware such as multer (and possibly others that are added through the route) instead of `express.use()`?

as I stated before, any and all of these routes can be enabled/disabled/modified through and admin panel, and I'd rather not have to add the actual routes to express and have my own middleware handling the requested routes.

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking, but you can dynamically call multer when you want it as in `const uploadSingle = upload.single('file');` and then within any route, you can conditionally call it with: `uploadSingle(req, res, next)`.  If you want to know yourself when it's done, then pass your own callback instead of `next` and it will call your callback when it's done.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you, that was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically call multer when you want it by first creating the middleware function:

```
const uploadSingle = upload.single('file');
```

and then within any route, you can conditionally call it with:

```
uploadSingle(req, res, next)
```

If you want to know yourself when it's done, then pass your own callback instead of next and it will call your callback when it's done.  Middleware doesn't have to be registered with Express so it can be automatically called by Express, you can call it with your own code (by just manually passing the right arguments from within a request handler) when you want it to act on a given request.  That gives you full conditional control.